# Android singleTask + AsyncTask and unexpected variable value changes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a main activity with launch mode set as "singleTask". When I bring it to the foreground and the onNewIntent method is called, it runs an AsyncTask containing a while loop which reads lines from a text file.

Part way into this loop, the value of one of my integer variables changes to 0. This doesn't always happen in the same stage in the loop cycle and the loop has nothing to do with this variable at all so I don't understand why this is happening.

Here's an image that might better explain the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogLQh.jpg

EDIT: Code as requested:

```
private class ReadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //Launch dialog
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... path) {

        try {

            File f = new File(path[0]);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
            InputStreamReader ir;
            ir = new InputStreamReader(in);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String str = new String();              

            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {         

                Log.i("My Variable",Integer.toString(myVariable));

                sb.append(str);
                sb.append("\n\n");

            }

            br.close();
            myTextFile = sb.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

        //Nothing here

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final String unusedString) {

        //Dismiss dialog

    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
        finish();
    }

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your AsyncTask implementation class?  It is difficult to diagnose the issue without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myVariable` seems to be changed from UI thread (activity thread). Try to add logging in each place where you modify myVariable.

Comment: Fixed it. You were right, it was being changed in another part of the UI thread which I kept overlooking.